# Ubuntu to Lubuntu? What would I lose?

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, desktop-environments

I'm running 18.04.6 LTS on an old Pavillon desktop and would like to give lubuntu a go.  I have a USB prepared.  Would this be like an update where all or most of my loaded software will still work.  Or would it be more like a fresh install on a wiped system?  (I'm not sure what works on what.)

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

dan@Pavilion:~$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
XFCE
```

Comment: I would recommend you to fresh install. If you try to keep all the software, then the gnome desktop environment will also remain. In case you have a separate home partition then you can keep your files. Otherwise, you will have to back up the files in your home partition.

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives.   You can add `lubuntu-desktop` to your existing system, which has the least changes (just adding extra now EOL software to your existing system) without re-install; you can use `ubuntu-support-status` to see security status, but do note Lubuntu/LXDE software will be adding more *unsupported* software to an 18.04 system.

Comment: Also note Lubuntu 18.04 was the last LXDE release; so a re-install is required to upgrade to a later system, you didn't specify what release you're asking about that has Lubuntu, you do mention 18.04.6 where no 18.04.6 media exists for any *flavors* of Ubuntu, as they'd reached already reached EOL (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ where you'll clearly see no flavors of Ubuntu are mentioned).  Also FYI:  You can re-install, including other desktops without losing files & having your *manually installed* applications auto-re-install.  You decide at install.

Comment: Since Lubuntu 18.04 is no longer supported, you can use Lubuntu 22.04 instead. However, Lubuntu 22.04 uses LXQt, which is not as lightweight as LXDE in Lubuntu 18.04. If you want to use LXDE on a supported operating system, you can use Debian LXDE edition instead.

Comment: You can install LXDE on your current system; I've done that on Ubuntu systems up to and including 22.04, being a fan of the old Lubuntu but not the new.  I am not sure about the support status, but the packages are still in the Ubuntu repos. (You can then choose which to log into on the signin screen.) If this approach appeals to you, let me know in a comment, and I'll post an answer.

Comment: I just installed lubuntu 22.04.1 on a chromebook so was thinking of using that.  I actually run Ubuntu 18.04 on 2 systems.  When I first updated to 18.04 on one, it got very very slow so I went to LXDE to make it run OK.  This make me think if I just go forward to the latest Ubuntu, it will be way too slow.  Wouldn't lubuntu be a safer call? Are there any procedures out there on how to get everything backed up for a clean install?

Comment: LXDE uses *deprecated* GTK2 which is light but almost completely unmaintained (*only small portions still used by `gimp` get maintenance*), but yes it's available on all current releases. If you're using LXDE & not Lubuntu, you can successfully upgrade 18.04; but if using Lubuntu meta packages, your 18.04 system will change to LXQt which is *unsupported*.  I've performed a number of such upgrades; some are clean & easy, one took me ~3 weeks to fix so it'll depend on what packages you've added how easy/hard it is (*what breaks*)

Comment: Is this machine still 32 bit?  It will restrict your options.

Answer (score 4):

**Does security matter to you?**

Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer

- https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/
- https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/

where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; flavors had shorter lives.

You can add `lubuntu-desktop` to your existing system, which has the least changes (*just adding extra now EOL software to your existing system*) without re-install; you can use `ubuntu-support-status` to see security status, but do note Lubuntu/LXDE software will be adding more *unsupported* (*no guarantee of support*) software to an 18.04 system.

Also note Lubuntu 18.04 was the last LXDE release; so a re-install is required to upgrade to a later system, you didn't specify what release you're asking about that has Lubuntu, you do mention 18.04.6 where no 18.04.6 media exists for any [*flavors* of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours), as they'd reached already reached EOL (see https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/ where you'll clearly see no flavors of Ubuntu are mentioned).

Also FYI: You can re-install, including other desktops without losing files & having your *manually installed* packages/apps auto-re-install (*if available in Ubuntu repositories for the release*). You decide at install by the options you use.

FYI:  I've QA-tested LXDE on all releases up to and included 22.04, however it relies on many *deprecated* libraries that are no longer supported upstream, so it's a decision as to whether or not you still want to use it (*security wise etc*); but yeah it still does work.  Modern Lubuntu uses LXQt however, as LXDE *developers* joined with Razor-Qt *developers* and creating the replacement LXQt desktop as they blogged about when porting LXDE to GTK3 was deemed to *heavy* and against the L=Light aim of the project.

---

Lubuntu 18.04 LTS questions on this site are still on-topic, the *unsupported* nature I'm referring to is what you'll see with `ubuntu-support-status` because only packages from 'main' & 'restricted' come with 5 years of *guaranteed* support. Lubuntu (and *flavor* packages are from 'universe' and no longer supported by the Lubuntu team with all guarantees of fixes ending at 3 years from initial release). It's still possible for any MOTU (*master of the universe*) or a *Core-Dev* to make security changes until 2023-April, but teams no longer support the packages.  About 70% (*from memory*) of a Lubuntu 18.04 LTS install is from 'main' thus still gets security fixes  (*I still have a *rarely used* Lubuntu 18.04 LTS system installed; though I now consider it Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE & XFCE as I have both Lubuntu & Xubuntu desktops installed*)

Comment: Clarification here: the GUI components of Ubuntu 18.04 and all Lubuntu supported components of the Lubuntu 18.04 software are EOL - that includes LXDE.  Outside of the LXDE suite and other  Universe components that're in 18.04, security updates for core libs like OpenSSL, etc. are still ongoing until 2023 (next year) around April, after which 18.04 will be fully End of Standard Support

Comment: That is true.. Lubuntu 18.04 LTS questions on this site are still on-topic, the *unsupported* nature I'm referring to is what you'll see with `ubuntu-support-status` which I mention, as packages in 'main' & 'restricted' come with 5 years of support; however Lubuntu packages are from 'universe' and no longer support by the Lubuntu team.  It's still possible for any MOTU (*master of the universe, or core-dev*) to make security changes until 2023-April, but teams no longer support the packages.  About 70% (*from memory*) of a Lubuntu 18.04 LTS install is from 'main' thus still gets security fixes

Comment: FYI: I'm typing this on a 2008 desktop system, and I prefer using Lubuntu over Ubuntu for a number of reasons. Firstly I'm no fan of GNOME, whilst I have it installed too (*my system is bloated with many desktops installed*) I can only cope with it on occasion & not daily as it's not preference.  I'm happier with Lubuntu's LXQt (or even Xubuntu's Xfce), but the other major benefit is LXQt is much lighter, and on an old desktop system with limited resources - LXQt is far faster (esp. using Qt5 apps). The apps you'll use will decide the fastest/leanest desktop; ie. apps+desktop sharing resources

Comment: An example of a `ubuntu-support-status` can be found here - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/lubuntu-18-04-lts-end-of-life-30-april-2021/2466/7  (from the old IBM Thinkpad t43 (*i386*) that I still have running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (with LXDE & Xfce).  Note: it's the 70% I remembered; but that figure will include all the apps I've added to the system where my systems tend to be bloated (hey it's got `xubuntu-desktop` to it for a start) so the percentages will vary to a clean Lubuntu 18.04 LTS system

Answer (score 0):

First, upgrade to a more recent version of Ubuntu (LTS).

Then,

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

This will transform your Ubuntu experience into Lubuntu, but without removing any software you already have installed.  You could still remove the Lubuntu components again if you wish, or even choose to log into a Gnome session or change your desktop manager without uninstalling anything.